# Error in Eclipse at start-up

Tags: eclipse

I am trying to get into Eclipse/Android programming but, sadly enough, I'm not even succeeding in running the HelloAndroid program!

I might have two types of problem. One is related to the AVD manager (just posted another question on that regards). The second is on Eclipse itself: when I start it (just after having re-installed it), without loading any project, I already get an error message: "**Invalid preference page path: XMl Syntax**", apparently related to plug-in **org.eclipse.ui**.

The log also says:

- "An exception stack trace is not available"
- eclipse.buildId=M20110909-1335
- java.version=1.7.0_01
- java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
- BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=it_IT
- Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86

FYI, I have installed Eclipse on an external HD (F:), but pointing to my main HD (C:) for storing projects. Could it be the cause?

Before I get deeper into troubleshooting, I would like to sort out this error. Can anybody help me?

Thanks
Bob

Answer (score 0):

looks more like a misconfigured installation.

try following:

download android sdk and extract it somewhere
start android sdk manager and install your preferred sdk's

download eclipse for rcp and rap developers
copy your java6 "jre" folder into the eclipse folder
start eclipse and configure the path to your extracted android sdk

this should work!

Comment: The path to the Android SDK looks OK (checked in the "windows\preference" menu). I am using the Eclipse "Classic 3.7.1" version and JRE7. All the three of them (Android SDK, Eclipse, JRE7) are installed on the same disk (f:\programs). I have already reinstalled all of them once. What is the difference with the RCP/RAP version? I' planning to try programming for Android devices - do you suggest me to use this RCP/RAP anyway?

Comment: you need to compile your java app with jdk/jre 6!
everything before gingerbread was done in java 5
after that java 6

i was building ics last weekend and it needed a jdk 6!